# interacting with an enum as an interface in other contract

Tags: solidity, remix, evm, interfaces, enum

having this issue of using enum as interface in other contract:
will appreciate your help...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.9;

interface interEnum {
    enum SIDE {
        buy,
        sell
    }
}

contract B is interEnum {

    function bEnum(SIDE side) external {
        // do something with here
    }
}

contract A {
    B b;
    enum NUM {
        buy,
        sell
    }
    function bEnum(NUM num) external {
        // i cant pass in an enum from here.
        // invalid explicit conversion from uint256 to Enum when i tried it this way
        // b.bEnum(uint256(num);

        // b
        // invalid explicit conversion from enum to enum....
        // b.bEnum(num);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled and cleaned up a bit so the Type is declared in one place only (DRY).

You can convert an enum to a number but you have to go through intermediary conversions to get there. Since there are only two members in the enum, it fits in a `uint8` so that conversion is possible. You have to go there first before you can convert to a `uint256`.

In most cases, you will hardly ever convert between enums and numbers. Numbers generally imply some sort of gradient while enums make things more readable when you want hard-coded categories or states.

In any case, this compiles and works as expected.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.9;

library Types {

    enum Side {
        buy,
        sell
    }
}

contract B {

    event TookSide(string side);

    function bEnum(Types.Side side) external {
        // Do something with it here
        if(side == Types.Side.buy) emit TookSide("buy");
        if(side == Types.Side.sell) emit TookSide("sell");
    }
}

contract A {

    B b;

    constructor(address _b) {
        b = B(_b);
    }

    function takeSide(Types.Side side) external returns(uint thing) {
        b.bEnum(side);
        thing = uint256(uint8(side));
    }
}
```

```
[
    {
        "from": "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
        "topic": "0x39053e506755f3eaf8479a64ca6444658a68a5886c5992c63649ab2d3cd476d8",
        "event": "TookSide",
        "args": {
            "0": "sell",
            "side": "sell"
        }
    }
]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does not allow implicit conversion from `A.NUM` to `interEnum.SIDE`, nor will it allow an explicit conversion like `b.bEnum(SIDE(num))`. Since your `b.bEnum()` takes `SIDE` as a param, you should pass the param of type `interEnum.SIDE` only.

```
contract A is interEnum {
    B b;

    function bEnum(SIDE num) external {
       b.bEnum(num);
    }
}
```